# Resample test for difference in means - null distribution is it right?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference, permutation-test, resampling

I'm struggling a bit with intuition behind resampling tests for difference in means.
I've two samples s1 and s2 of size n1 and n2 respectively. Population parameters are unknown. I'd like to know if the means of the two populations from which the samples came are different.

The Permutation approach for this I've read to be:

1. Note the observed difference in mean between s1 and s2.
2. Combine both s1 and s2 into a single large pool
3. Draw n1 samples compute the mean. Compute the mean of the remaining n2 samples and compute the difference between the two. Note this difference down.
4. repeat the above a large number of times, thus getting a distribution for difference in means.
5. Test the observed difference in mean in step 1 against the distribution in step 4 for significance.

My problem is - The NULL distribution generated in step 4, wouldn't that be wrong if the samples were actually from populations that did have different means? What we get in step 4, seems to a distribution of difference in means when the two populations are combined without any relevance to whether the means were the same. How can this be used as the null distribution - where the null hypothesis is supposed to be that the two populations have same mean?

I have the same question for bootstrap as well (i.e., In step 4, if we draw samples of size n1 and n2 with replacement)

Thanks!